# Visual Composer Front-End Only available to Users

Tags: wordpress, visual-composer

I have a listing site with 41 different members. I want them to be able to login and then be presented with just their own member post and the ability to edit it with the visual composer front-end editor. No other pages should be available to them while they are logged in as this user.

I have tried various plugin combinations to create different roles then limit them to only edit their own posts but this always goes via the wordpress admin area. I just want them to stay front-end the whole time.

I'm pretty sure that this would be a common requirement but after a lot of searching I can't seem to find the solution to the problem. Does anybody know of a plugin or a plugin combination that would allow for this?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out I have found a way to do what I wanted in case anybody is searching for this.

The plugin 'Peter’s Login Redirect' allows me to redirect directly to the frontend editor url created by visual composer. This means that on login my users are taken directly to the editor and never see the backend.

That works for me.